# ¿Como puedo mejorar mi codigo + relacion de tablas?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, mariadb, apache-netbeans

Muy buenas, esta es mi primera consulta y quisiera saber si me pueden orientar acerca de un codigo que tengo hecho pero tengo un problema, primero los pondre en contexto, estoy desarrollando un login con roles en java, la base de datos es en mariadb, la relacion de las tablas es la siguiente:
[image: Tabla reportes]

[image: Tabla usuarios]

Por ejemplo al ingresar como operario que es un rol de usuario y deseo registrar un reporte, esta es la consulta que hago al dar clic en mi boton registrar:

```
String operario = op1.getText();
       String maquina = mq1.getText();
        String fecha = fecha1.getText();
        String turno = turno1.getText();
        String codigo = codigo1.getText();
        String hora = hora1.getText();
        String cliente = cliente1.getText();
        String numeRollo = numRollo1.getText();
        String op_opc = op_opc1.getText();
        String anchoR = anchoR1.getText();
        String produ = produccion1.getText();
        String anchoLargo = anchoLargo1.getText();
        String observaciones = obs1.getText();
        String firma = firma1.getText();
if (operario.equals("") || maquina.equals("") || fecha.equals("") || turno.equals("") || codigo.equals("")
                || hora.equals("") || cliente.equals("") || numeRollo.equals("") || op_opc.equals("") || anchoR.equals("")
                 || produ.equals("") || anchoLargo.equals("") || observaciones.equals("") || firma.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Campos vacios, por favor dijite todos los campos", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            try {
            ConexionBD c = new ConexionBD();
            String query = "insert into reportes(operario, maquina, fecha, turno, codigo, hora, cliente,"
            + " num_rollo, op_opc, ancho_r, produccion, ancho_largo, observaciones, firma) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = c.connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, operario);
            statement.setString(2, maquina);
            statement.setString(3, fecha);
            statement.setString(4, turno);
            statement.setString(5, codigo);
            statement.setString(6, hora);
            statement.setString(7, cliente);
            statement.setString(8, numeRollo);
            statement.setString(9, op_opc);
            statement.setString(10, anchoR);
            statement.setString(11, produ);
            statement.setString(12, anchoLargo);
            statement.setString(13, observaciones);
            statement.setString(14, firma);

            int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();

            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                // si se insertó correctamente
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Reporte creado correctamente", "Éxito", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                // si no se insertó correctamente
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error al crear el reporte", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

El error que me sale es que desconoce el id_usuario de la tabla reportes, estoy un poco confundido porque crei que como es mi foranea automaticamente al ingresar con mi usuario operario me iba a relacionar mi reporte con ese usuario.
Muchas gracias por su atencion

Comment: Una cosa no tiene nada que ver con la otra.. tu programa sabe (o por lo menos lo tiene en algun lado, o deberia) el id_usuario.. pero la query, no tiene ni idea de eso.. si no le decis con que id_usuario conectar el nuevo registro, no va a poder...